# Nginx rewrite: Redirect .php files to it's related rewritten url?

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

I have nginx re-write config as below:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location / { 
    try_files $uri $uri.php $uri/ =404;
    rewrite ^/about/$ /about.php;
}
```

`/about/` this url is working fine, and showing content of `about.php` file.

But I want when someone try to access `about.php` directly then they should get either `/about/` or if related file url re-write is not present then they should get 404.

Please help how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you.

```
location /about {
try_files $uri $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
}

location @extensionless-php {
rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}
```

Ref: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-remove-php-using-nginx

Comment: Hi @Nabeel, I have checked this but it is not working when I try to access https://example.com/about.php it is still showing that about.php page. Not redirecting to /about/ url.

Comment: Hello, @Parshant, If this is not working for you then you better change approach to fix this problem. Your index.php should dynamic and should be able to include relevant file as per request. For example
Without URL Rewrite your pages should be accessible like http://example.com/index.php?page=about
With URL Rewrite your pages should be accessible like http://example.com/about
Remove "rewrite ^/about/$ /about.php;" from nginx config